# How can i get userId of aws account?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am using a API call to retrieve the plaintext instance identity document. Here, accountId is present.

```
response = response.get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document").text
```

I am using the above code in my python script. How can i get AWS userId by API call?

Comment: User id of what? The above URL is for meta data about the EC2 instance :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but [get_caller_identity](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity) returns `UserId` and `Accountid`:

> **UserId** (string) The unique identifier of the calling entity. The exact value depends on the type of entity that is making the call. The
>   values returned are those listed in the aws:userid column in the
>   Principal table found on the Policy Variables reference page in the
>   IAM User Guide .
>
> **Account** (string) The AWS account ID number of the account that owns or contains the calling entity.
>
> **Arn** (string) The AWS ARN associated with the calling entity.

Example output is (from [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity)):

```
'Account': '123456789012',
'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice',
'UserId': 'AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE'
```

Comment: When i doing this, it gives some error can you figure out? I am attaching some last lines of code. ` File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\signers.py", line 90, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\signers.py", line 160, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`

Comment: @rahulsharma If you running your python on your local workstation, first have to configure your credentials. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) are instructions.

Comment: How can i get "account name" ?

Comment: @rahulsharma I don't know what do you mean by account name. The AWS sdk returns only what I wrote, UserId, AccountId and Arn. Nothing else.

Comment: account name contains email id, i want to get that login email id in my python script.

Comment: I'm not aware of any sdk for this. This is only for root of the account, just like root's creddit card and billing details.